# Datagridview cell validation on focus out

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I have a datagridview in my form how can I validate the cells on leaving the current row.

Comment: I'm confused... there is an asp.net tag but isn't DataGridView a Windows Forms control?

Answer (score 0):

On each selected index changed save the current index but before you save it just get the data from the previous selected row and validate it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for Windows Forms (the question is tagged ASP.NET but as far as I know there is no such thing as a DataGridView for the web):

Handle the `RowValidating` event and validate the row there. If the row's values are invalid, set the error message in the `ErrorText` property of the row, and set `e.Cancel = True`.

Finally in the `RowValidated` event, set the row's `ErrorText` property to an empty string.